# How to returning BigQuery table rows with a max value

Tags: google-bigquery

I've a simple bigquery table with 3 columns (and some example data) below:

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------|
|      Name           |     Time         |  Value     |
|---------------------|------------------|------------|
|          a          |         1        |   x        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------|
|          a          |         2        |   y        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------|
|          a          |         3        |   z        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------|
|          b          |         1        |   x        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------|
|          b          |         4        |   y        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------|
```

For **each** name, I'd like to return the value with the **max** time.

For the above table the 3rd and 5th row should be returned, e.g.,

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------|
|      Name           |     Time         |  Value     |
|---------------------|------------------|------------|
|          a          |         3        |   z        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------|
|          b          |         4        |   y        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------|
```

It is roughly like: (1) first group by Name, (2) find out the max time in each group, (3) identify the row with the max time.

Seems for (1) and (2), we can use group by + max(), but i'm not sure how to achieve the (3) step.

Anyone has ideas of what's the best query I can write to achieve this purpose.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 18):

`ROW_NUMBER` is one way to go here:

```sql
SELECT Name, Time, Value
FROM
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Time DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable
) t
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Using `QUALIFY` we can try:

```sql
SELECT Name, Time, Value
FROM yourTable
WHERE TRUE
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Time DESC) = 1;
```

Comment: far more efficient

Comment: This can also be done using `QUALIFY` to avoid the subquery.

Comment: @LiamGalbraith Could you please suggest how to use `QUALIFY` properly in this case?

Comment: @M4rk Check the updated answer to see how to use `QUALIFY` with `ROW_NUMBER`.

Answer (score 6):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT AS VALUE ARRAY_AGG(t ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)]
FROM `project.dataset.table` t 
GROUP BY name
```

if to apply to sample data from your question as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'a' name, 1 time, 'x' value UNION ALL
  SELECT 'a', 2, 'y' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'a', 3, 'z' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b', 1, 'x' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b', 4, 'y' 
)
SELECT AS VALUE ARRAY_AGG(t ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)]
FROM `project.dataset.table` t 
GROUP BY name
```

result is

```
Row name    time    value    
1   a       3       z    
2   b       4       y
```