# BigQuery Error: SELECT list expression references esthetician.LICENSE_TYPE which is neither grouped nor aggregated at [49:8]

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a use case where I need to find the maximum count of each licensed professionals from the counties of Texas. Based on another post I found, I used the QUALIFY function in BigQuery like so:

```
SELECT 
    esthetician.LICENSE_TYPE, 
    COUNT(esthetician.LICENSE_TYPE), 
    esthetician.COUNTY
FROM 
    `charcoflptexas.texas_cosmetologists.cosmetologists` AS esthetician
    JOIN `charcoflptexas.texas_cosmetologists.texasCountyCensus` AS census 
        ON TRIM(esthetician.COUNTY) = TRIM(census.NAME)
WHERE 
    TRUE 
QUALIFY 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY esthetician.LICENSE_TYPE ORDER BY COUNT(esthetician.LICENSE_TYPE) DESC) = 1;
```

But I keep getting this error:

> SELECT list expression references esthetician.LICENSE_TYPE which is neither grouped nor aggregated at [49:8]

- [How to returning BigQuery table rows with a max value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61883390/how-to-returning-bigquery-table-rows-with-a-max-value)

This is what I am trying to solve as well. I tried both codes that were posted as answers but the error persists.

I tried using GROUP BY but that is not working as well.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added the missing GROUP BY like shown below. Please note the `LicenseType` in `ORDER BY LicenseCount DESC,LicenseType ASC`. This is added in order to make result stable when multiple license types have equal count. You may want to return all rows in such cases, please see `RANK()` at the bottom of this answer.

```
with test_data_table as (
    select 
        'County #1' as COUNTY,
        'License type #1' as LICENSE_TYPE

    union all

    select 'County #1', 'License type #2'

    union all

    select 'County #1', 'License type #2'

    union all     

    select 'County #2', 'License type #2'

    union all     

    select 'County #2', 'License type #3'

    union all     

    select 'County #2', 'License type #4'
)

select 
    COUNTY as County,
    LICENSE_TYPE as LicenseType,
    count(LICENSE_TYPE) as LicenseCount
from
    test_data_table
group by 
    County, LicenseType
qualify
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY County ORDER BY LicenseCount DESC,LicenseType ASC) = 1
```

Returns

[image]

If you want to return rows with equal count, please replace `ROW_NUMBER()` with `RANK()` like this

```
select 
    COUNTY as County,
    LICENSE_TYPE as LicenseType,
    count(LICENSE_TYPE) as LicenseCount
from
    test_data_table
group by 
    County, LicenseType
qualify
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY County ORDER BY LicenseCount DESC) = 1
```

Returns

[image]